# Angular - file upload request, adding @RequestParam

Tags: angularjs, spring, http, spring-mvc

I want to add `@RequestParam` to my `http` request so it will match spring MVC `@RequestParam`.

How can I add this to my file upload request:

```
/*
@param file - file from input

@param uploadUrl - url
*/    

    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
                var fd = new FormData();
                //add file to FormData
                fd.append(file.name, file);
                //send request
                $http.post(uploadUrl, fd,  {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                })
                .success(function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .error(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
```

In my backend the error is `Required String parameter 'filename' is not present`
Here is my Spring MVC `controller` (only the header part):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileUploadController {
    /**
     * Upload single file using Spring Controller
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("filename") String filename, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
//rest of the function
```

}

Comment: I presume you have consulted the documentation for either Angular `$http` or `FormData` and tried to add the parameters as described. What problems did you experience?

Comment: The backend error - Required String parameter 'filename' is not present, error code 400

Comment: Never mind, i figure it out myself, posting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just append another param to my `FormData`:

```
fd.append('file', file);
fd.append('filename', file.name);
```

Match the `@RequestParam`'s.

Thanks.